# Should RabbitMQ take this long to setup the connection?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am trying a basic hello world example with RabbitMQ in Python, and it is taking about 8 seconds to set up a basic blocking connection.  This seems excessive, but this is my first experience with RabbitMQ, so my question is: is this normal?  Can I reduce this time?  Or should I look for another option?  Here is my code:

```
import time
import pika

start = time.time()

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host="localhost"))

end = time.time()

print "Elapsed time: %s" % (end-start)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue="hello")
channel.basic_publish(exchange="",
                      routing_key="hello",
                      body="Hello world!")
connection.close()
```

and my output is `Elapsed time: 8.01042914391`.

Thanks for the help!

[Edit]  I have noticed that every time I run it, it takes almost exactly 8 seconds, to within .2%.  I'm not sure if that means anything.

Comment: Normally - it doesn't. But it really depends on available to RabbitMQ broker resources. If RabbitMQ runs int flow control mode, then such delay also can be called "normal", so I guess originally you want to find out why it takes so long. But without extra information like platform, versions, resources, logs it is hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure channel configurations for inbound channel, outbound chanel, just like thread pool executor. Default values for these threads is 1 which might  cause in delay under some load.